# How do you keep MVC validation messages from disappearing when you click on another field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-validation

I have a asp.net MVC/Razor project.  One of the views has a series of dropdowns.  When you select an option from the dropdown, javascript code checks to see if the option has already been selected by another dropdown.  If it has, the validation message is set and warns the user.  This is all working fine.  The problem is, when I click on another dropdown or text box, the validation message disappears.  Also, the form can now be submitted.  What do I need to do to keep the validation message on the screen?

Here's the partial code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ChallengeQuestion", "Admin"))
{
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Q1, Model.QuestionList, "---Select Question---")<br />
 <span class="validation">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Q1)</span>
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Ans1)

 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Q2, Model.QuestionList, "---Select Question---")<br />
 <span id = "spValidQ2" class="validation">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Q2)</span>
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Ans2)

 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Q3, Model.QuestionList, "---Select Question---")<br />
 <span class="validation">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Q3)</span>
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Ans3)

  <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
}

<script>
    $("#Q2").change(
        function () {
            if ($("#Q2").val() == $("#Q1").val()) {
                $("#spValidQ2 .field-validation-valid").text("This question has already been used.");
            }
        })
```

So what's happening is that the the user selects an option from dropdown Q1.  When they select an option from Q2, the javascript checks if it's the same value from Q1.  If it is, it shows the error message.  This part is working.  The problem is, now that the error messge is there, if I click on anothera control, say the Q3 dropdown or the Ans1 textbox, the error message disappears.

What I want to happen is for the javascript to show the error message on the screen until the value in the Q2 dropdown is changed to be something other than the value for Q1.  I also want to prevent the form from being submitted until this change is made.

Comment: Your code will never prevent the form from submitting - its in no way wired to `jquery.validate`. And it appears that your trying to put the message into the element used by unobtrusive validation so `jquery.validate` is taking over and removing the message because it is valid as far as your validation attributes are concerned. To do this correctly, you need to create your own validation attribute.

Comment: I'm not worried about the submit right now (of course I'm always willing to receive suggestions; I'm thinking of "catching" the submit in javascript and performing a check there), I'm asking about the validation message.  I inherited this project and validation is done this way throughout the code (setting the .field-validation-valid text in javascript).  My question is how can I keep this validation on the screen?

Comment: Firstly, client side validation is a nice bonus so you must validate on the server (any one can override client side validation) and the best way to get both is by using a a validation attribute (that implements `IClientValidatable`). But you issue is that you rendering the message inside the element specifically used for MVC validation. As soon as you loose focus, client side validation kicks in, see that the property is valid (unless you have selected the "-select question-" option) and clears the contents.

Comment: You should delete the script (any any other scripts attempting to add messages this way) and do it correctly. Consider using a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[NotEqualTo]` or similar attribute if you don't want to write your own. But if you really want to do it this way, you could always add another html element and add the message there.

Comment: Unfortunately, "correctly" isn't always easy to define.  In my case, I inherited this project with a certain validation and my bosses want me to use a consistent approach throughout.  You mentioned client side validation is causing it to disappear.  Is there a way to disable that client side validation (either altogether or on specific elements)?

Comment: "is there a way to disable client side validation" - yes, simply stop using `@Html.ValidationFor` which is *specifically* for client side validation.  Just use the `span` and maybe style it to match the validationfor.  If this is not acceptable, then either your 'bosses' have lost site of the business requirement or, as I suspect, they want you to use client-side validation but with a custom validator, the previous 'foolproof' link will either match what you need or point you to how to write your own.